# Add String value on Array

Tags: php

I want to add a string code ("CUS") with $row['id'] number. how can I do that?
for example, if id value is 1 then it should display as CUS1.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($empRecords)) {
$data[] = array(
        "id"=>$row['id'],
        "name"=>$row['name'],
        "id_no"=>$row['id_no'],
        "address"=>$row['address'],
        "grmadiv"=>$row['grmadiv'],
        "mobile"=>$row['mobile'],
        "branch"=>$row['branch'],
        "loanOfcr"=>$row['loanOfcr'],
        "collectOfcr"=>$row['collectOfcr']
    );
```

Comment: You mean like this ` "code" => 'CUS'.$row['id']; `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place any string Concatenation with ".", Example like

"id"=> 'CUS'. $row['id'],

$code = 'CUS'.$row['id];

Thanks